# Inequality of a L-2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Now I am trying to prove following fact:

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ $\in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$. Assuming that $||AC||_{2} \neq 0$, $||BC||_{2} \neq 0$, $C^{ij} \neq 0$ (each element of $C$ is not equal to $0$), then if $||AC||_{2} \leq 1$ and $||B||_{2} \leq ||A||_{2}$, prove $||BC||_{2} \leq 1$.

Can anybody give me some hints. Thank you!

~Edit~:

At present, I knew the following fact for a vector norm: given $x \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ and $y \in \mathbb{F}^{m}$ then $||x|| \leq ||y||$ if and only if there is a matrix $\Delta \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times m}$ with $||\Delta|| \leq 1$ such that $x = \Delta y$.

My problem will be solved if the above fact can be extended to a matrix norm. But now I am unable to prove that extension.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true at all.  Consider 
$$ A = B = \pmatrix{2 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr},\ C = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr} $$

EDIT: For the revised question, try

$$ B = C = \pmatrix{2 & \epsilon\cr \epsilon & \epsilon\cr},\ A = \pmatrix{\epsilon & \epsilon\cr \epsilon & 2\cr}$$
where $\epsilon \ne 0$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. But could you please consider my edited post?

Comment: I have checked your recommendation and it is correct. However, I tried a special version of the above faulty fact and it seem to be correct. The detail of revision is given as my below answer. Could you please further give me a advice on it?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @RobertIsrael, the claim of my initial post is wrong. However, it seem to be correct in following special case:

Assuming $A = \begin{bmatrix}A_{1} & 0\\0 & A_{2}\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{F}^{2 \times 2}$, $B = \begin{bmatrix}B_{1} & 0\\0 & B_{2}\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{F}^{2 \times 2}$ (with $A_{1}, A_{2}, B_{1}, B_{2} \ne 0$), and $C \in \mathbb{F}^{2 \times 2}$ ($C$ has full rank and $C^{ij} \ne 0$).

Prove that: if $||B_{1}||_{2} \leq ||A_{1}||_{2}$, $||B_{2}||_{2} \leq ||A_{2}||_{2}$, and $||AC||_{2} \leq 1$ then $||BC||_{2} \leq 1$.

Any idea or comment are appreciated. Thank you!